# Two elements of $\mathbb F_{q^m}$ that share the same minimal polynomial over $\mathbb F_q$ have the same multiplicative order

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

Let $\mathbb F_{q^m}$ be the field with $q^m$ elements, where $q$ is a prime number (constructed as the quotient field $\mathbb F_q[x]/(p)$, where $p$ is an irreducible, monic polynomial over $\mathbb F_q$). Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb F_{q^m}$, so that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ share the same the same minimal polynomial $m_\alpha$ over $\mathbb F_q$.

I now want to show that $\alpha, \beta$ have the same order in $\mathbb F_{q^m}^\times$ (the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{q^m}$). Using that, I'm then supposed to conclude that $m \mid \phi(q^m - 1)$, where $\phi$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

Now my idea was to maybe look at the multiplicative, cyclic subgroup $\langle \alpha \rangle$ of $\mathbb F_{q^m}^\times$ (the subgroup that's generated by $\alpha$). Now we have $\mid \langle \alpha \rangle \mid = \text{ order of } \alpha \text{ in } \mathbb F_{q^m}^\times =: ord_{\mathbb F_{q^m}^\times}(\alpha)$.

Now I suspect that it's true that $\langle \alpha \rangle = \langle \beta \rangle$, from which the first statement would follow right away. But I'm not sure how I could derive that from only the fact that $\alpha, \beta$ are roots of the same minimal polynomial in $\mathbb F_q$.

(I'm also open to any other approaches – this was just the first that came to mind.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplicative order of $\alpha$ is the minimum $k$ such that $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{k} - 1$.

Now if $F$ is a field and $f \in F[x]$, the following are equivalent

- $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, and
- the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ divides $f$.

---

So the multiplicative order of $\alpha$ is the minimum $k$ such that $m_{\alpha} \mid x^{k} -1$. And the multiplicative order of $\beta$ is the minimum $h$ such that $m_{\beta} \mid x^{h} -1$. But $m_{\alpha} = m_{\beta}$, thus...

---

As to the second part, $\varphi(q^m - 1)$ is the number of generators of the cyclic group of non-zero elements of the field with $q^{m}$ elements. Every such generator generates the field with $q^{m}$ elements over the field with $q$ elements, and thus its minimal polynomial over the field with $q$ elements has degree $m$. But by the first part all the $m$ roots of such a minimal polynomial have the same multiplicative order, hence the number of generators of the cyclic group of non-zero elements of the field with $q^{m}$ elements is a multiple of $m$.

Comment: An alternative proof makes use of the fact that $\beta = \alpha^{q^{t}}$ for some $t$, and that the order of $\alpha$ is coprime to $q$. But this requires a bit of Galois theory.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just a little confused still, is $x^k - 1$ always the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ then? Do we know that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha \in \mathbb F_{q^m}$ in $\mathbb F_q$ has always this shape? Then I see why the statement would follow quickly.

Comment: I have edited the answer for clarity. $x^{k} - 1$ is reducible, so it is never a minimum polynomial in this context.

Comment: Ah ok, now I see. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, I know I already accepted your answer but do you have an idea how from that, I could derive the 2nd part of the question; that is, that we have $m \mid \phi(q^m - 1)$? I know that $ m_\alpha = \prod_{j \in C_i} (x - a^j)$ when $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb F_{q^m}^\times$, and where $a^i = \alpha$ and $C_i$ is the respective cyclotomic coset. I thought I could get somewhere from there using the first part of the question, but I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: @moran, I've written it up.

Comment: nice, thanks again.